# Visual Studio Code PHP Intelephense auto formats Null Coalescing Operator

Tags: javascript, php, visual-studio-code, intelephense

I'm using PHP Intelephense(free) extension in vscode and we use CodeIgniter 3 in our project and it works well with models and controller, but in my pages/view where javascript,css,jquery is written. Null Coalescing Operator happens to be auto formatting by PHP Intelephense by separating the questions (from ?? to ? ?) automatically. Is their no way to ignore this rule in PHP Intelephense?

```
  return data ?? '--';
```

when doing auto formatting (in mac) (option + shift + f) its turning into this which causes error.

```
  return data ? ? '--';
```

Comment: I'm using DataTable library and it is inside a render function.

render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
return data ? ? '--';
}

Answer (score 0):

I have made an alternative solution to my own problem. by adding a grave accent in the return then calling the expression inside a template literal.

return `${data ?? '--'}`

Forcing the php Intelephense to ignore the said line.